How to approach a one-way ANOVA with SOME dependence?
I am looking to compare several groups using a one-way ANOVA. Each group is independent from one-another, but the samples within each group have some dependence to one-another (i.e. some (or all) of the samples in a group come from the same subject, but measured at a different time (time measured is irrelevant here)).
Is a one-way ANOVA appropriate for this task? Would, for example, using the means for each subject as a single datapoint within a group make this more appropriate? Does this change if all groups are a single subject each?

Repeated-measures ANOVA?

@Dave Would that work for an uneven number of samples per subject? And would I then lose the original groupings, if groups have >1 subject?

Maybe try cluster your standard errors at the group level?

Here's how I would approach the problem:
The DGP is
$$
Y_{iut}=\mu_i+\nu_t+\xi_u+\varepsilon_{iut}=\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k\cdot\mathbb1(i=k)+\sum_{l=1}^m\beta_l\cdot\mathbb 1(t=l)+\sum_{p=1}^s \gamma_p\cdot\mathbb 1(u=p)+\varepsilon_{iut}
$$
where $Y_{it}$ is the observed outcome variable for individual $i$ in group $u$ at time $t$, $\mu_i$ are individual fixed effects (which is equivalent to $n$ dummy variables, where $n$ is the total number of individuals), $\nu_t$ are time fixed effects (equivalent to $m$ dummy variables, where $m$ is the total number of time periods), $\xi_u$ are group fixed effects, $\varepsilon_{iut}$ is the error term. Note that we allow $\varepsilon_{it}$ to correlate at the individual level. To do that we can use clustered standard errors (I suggest reading the article "When Should You Adjust Standard Errors for Clustering?" for more about clustered s.e.'s). In R fixest package, if you add individual fixed effects to the model, it will automatically cluster standard errors for you. Just run something like
feols(Y ~ 1 | id + year + group)

or use base R lm with starprep() from package estimatr to get clustered s.e.'s.
However, note that $F$-tests are not heteroskedasticity- and autocorrelation-robust. You might want to use a Wald test or a LM test for your ANOVA omnibus test (assuming first dummy dropped and replaced with a constant term):
$$
\gamma_p=0,\ \forall 2\leq p\leq s,
$$
and for your post-hoc tests, just run your model with a different group dummy dropped each time and run $t$-tests on the regression coefficients (with clustered s.e.'s, of course). You can also add other control variables ("covariates") to the model.
